# error: unknown host service when reinstall_apps in calabash-android

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I tried to install test.apk with calabash-android but always failed with following reason. 
Following are my steps:

```
Calabash-android resign test.apk
calabash-android build test.apk
calabash-android gen
calabash-android console test.apk
reinstall_apps
```

and met following errors, can anyone help a guide where is the problem? THanks.

```
irb(main):001:0> reinstall_apps
error: unknown host service
error: unknown host service
error: unknown host service
error: unknown host service
error: unknown host service
error: unknown host service
error: unknown host service
NoMethodError: undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/c
alabash-android/operations.rb:333:in `install_app'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/c
alabash-android/operations.rb:309:in `reinstall_apps'
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/calabash-android-0.7.3/lib/c
alabash-android/operations.rb:106:in `reinstall_apps'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Comment: D:\AutomationTest>calabash-android version
0.7.3

Comment: D:\AutomationTest>ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x64-mingw32]

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear exactly what you are trying to do or your understanding of calabash. Here is an intro guide to help you get set up

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bslZMzEkPeU&list=PLInoIpH9dfLyvdaOjozON9QnQP1pK30y-

If you are past all of this, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that the reason is that Android studio occupy port "5037" that blocks calabash-android's operation.

Just end of the process which take port 5037 works.

THanks all.